# C++ Enum Names Overlap

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

Lets say I have a class which contains two enums.

```
    enum NameType { Defined, Inherited };
    enum ValueType { Defined, Inherited };
```

The numeration values are said to be "previously defined" in the second enum because they have the same names as the first enum. Is there a syntax that is concise and allows for these names?

I know in C# this isn't a problem, but in C++ it seems to be. I'm using C++11.

Comment: Can you use C++11's `enum class`? http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html

Comment: Say `enum class NameType { Defined, Inherited };` to make them distinct.

Comment: Then scoped enums it is!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're using C++11, I'd recommend using [`enum class`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Strongly_typed_enumerations).

```
enum class NameType { Defined, Inherited };
enum class ValueType { Defined, Inherited };
```

This fixes the scoping issue.

See http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html for further discussion of `enum class`.

Comment: Thanks. That's it. I missed how the class keyword should be added.

Comment: Worth using its real name: _scoped enums_. It's a separate feature from enums.

Comment: @russ note this changes a lot about how the enum operates.  No more implicit conversion!

Comment: Anything else? So use static_cast<int>(c) instead of just (int)c? right?

Comment: And in C++03 you can have something very similar, by putting the enum inside a namespace of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this by prefixing all your enums with an abbreviation of the name of the enum. This is how many libraries handle this. In your case this would be the result:

```
enum NameType { NT_Defined, NT_Inherited };
enum ValueType { VT_Defined, VT_Inherited };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have C++11 compiler, you can use namespaces or classes:

```
namespace Solar
{
   enum NameType { Defined, Inherited };
}

namespace Lunar
{
   enum ValueType { Defined, Inherited };
}
```

Of course, if you use `using namespace`, compiler may give error for ambiguity. But that error would be easy to resolve by just using fully qualified name. On similar lines, you may also define enums in `public` region of a class.

Comment: I actually eventually opted for this solution so that I don't have to define my own bit-wise |, &, ==, != operators. This seems to be a rather broken feature of the strongly typed enums that they don't have working operators by default.